# Has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, has-many-through

I have two models with a has_many_through association, like this:

```
class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dashboards_workspaces
  has_many :dashboards, through: :dashboards_workspaces
end
```

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dashboards_workspaces
  has_many :workspaces, through: :dashboards_workspace
end
```

When I create a dashboard I have the option to select one or more workspaces and I'm able to get the dashboards with a workspace like this:

```
Dashboard.joins(:workspaces).all
```

And I'm getting the workspaces_ids this way:

```
foo = Dashboard.find(1)
foo.workspaces.id
```

But I need to only show in the view the dashboards that have the same workspace_id as the current user:

```
@workspaces = Workspace.where(id: current_user.workspaces)
```

For example:

```
Workspace.where(id: current_user.workspaces) = [4]
Dashboard.find(1).workspaces.id = [1, 3]
Dashboard.find(2).workspaces.id = [4]
```

I need to only show dashboard 2 in the view.

Is there a way that I can accomplish that using a query in my controller?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: it would be helpful is you could share the association of your user model too

Comment: edited my answer to avoid repeated results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your user model `has_many :workspaces` if is the case I think you can do something like this:

```rb
workspaces_ids = current_user.workspaces.pluck(:id)
dashboards = Dashboard.joins(:workspaces).where(Workspace.arel_table[:id].in(workspaces_ids)).distinct
```

The above should leave in `dashboards` all the dashboards that have `associations` with any of the `workspaces` inside `current_user.workspaces`.

Comment: Happy to help! 